# How to hook up satellite to computer to watch satellite TV on computer

Tags: dvi

I have a satellite receiver (or set-top-box) as shown below and I want to connect it to my computer in order to view digital TV on my computer. It has and is232c port and an AV port as seen from the figure. How should I connect this to my computer in order to watch satellite TV on computer? Can I use the its rs-232c port for this purpose?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

RS232 would be used to maintain the device - eg upgrade the firmware on it.  Most RS232 Ports are limited to 115400 baud (I know there are exceptions, but thats relevant) - At less then 128k, that is nowhere enough to send video and audio in the general case, and definately not the digital DVB transmission you would receive.

At a guess, if you really wanted to hook it up, you could get an AV capture card, and the appropriate AV cable.    This would be a cludge though.

A much better solution would be to get an appropriate DVB-T capture card.  You can get cheap USB ["DVB-T" tuner](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=&rmvSB=true&_osacat=3761&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xdvb-t.TRS0&_nkw=dvb-t&_sacat=3761) devices for about US$10 - just make sure it is compatible with the signal from your region.

Comment: Does this dvb-t tuner that you mentioned get input from my dvb receiver's A/V output as shown in the picture in the question body?

Comment: I did not mention a specific tuner, but typically no - they would take the raw signal off the aerial.  (You should be able to split the signal and send a copy to each device).  Note that you did not show the signal input - you just specified Digital TV Receiver - it is probable that this is DVB-T (if its hooked up to an aerial), but could also be DVB-S (hooked up to a Satellite) - similar but different protocols with different, but analogous USB or Intetface cards.

Comment: So, this is DVB-S, as it is hooked up to satellite. I'll add image correspondingly for satellite input on the receiver above.

Comment: Do you know what Satellite your dish is pointing at, and if you are only after Free-To-Air channels ?  (If so, I may be able to provide better advise on what standard to use - I happen to know a bit about DVB-S as I imported and (and used for myself) and sold tuner cards in my part of the world, so I have a fair idea what to look for)

Comment: Mostly, Arabsat and Hot Bird LNBs are mounted on dish in this region. Mine is Arabsat, and I only watch free-to-air channels.

Comment: There are a number Arabsat satellites so it could be overkill, but I would recommend you get a (more expensive) tuner card with DVB-S2  (those cards will work with the older DVB-S standard and the newer one, and at least on Arabsat Badr 4/5/7 there is quite a bit of HD content which requires S2).  The cheapest unit I found on EBAY was http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-FAT-HD-DVB-S2-DVB-S-MPEG-4-EPG-DVB-USB-PVR-HD-Digital-Satellite-Receiver-/391004471164?hash=item5b09aebf7c:g:caAAAOSwkNZUkGst  - but I've never seen that model.  (I'd use a TeVii S660 or similar, but can't see where to buy one)

Comment: is it possible to use an A/V to USB adaptor like [this](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/av-to-usb-converter) to connect my current receiver to computer? Then, the question for me is how the computer will recognize it as I have no drivers for the receiver (set-top-box).

Comment: If you believesome of the descriptions - yes, but I am HIGHLY DOUBTFUL as are others here. See <a href=”http://superuser.com/questions/306907/3-rca-to-usb-cable”>here</a> and if you do proceed make sure it comes with software. <a ref=http://www.ebay.com/bhp/usb-video-capture-device”> these</a> are a bit more expensive but should work.